# How refresh procedures of DBContext class in my EF model? (ASP.NET + ADO EDM)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

**Hello!**

After create .edmx from database i added to DB more stored procedures. After that i opened model diagram and press "Update model from database", choosed this procedures. But i can't use them in code and can't see them in *.tt files. Model browser contains their.

## tt file ##
[image: tt file of EDM]

Model browser: 
[image: Model Browser]

What is wrong?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to do:
1) Open edmx file model diagram. Press update from Database... ok.
2) Build |rebuild solution.
3) right click on the file under .edmx file in solution explorer... find item like run custom tool.

that's all.

Comment: You may need to change the properties of migration methods (thats double stored procedures) Than need right click on edmx file and open object model, or some item like this. Then find your changed migration method and click properties...

Answer (score 0):

What I found was only to delete .tt files and add dbcontext generator again. But I'm using Attributes for validation and during this process all entities are deleted and created again. So this is not good approach for me..;/